# Do we need both the joomla-4.x and joomla-4 tags?

Tags: discussion

The `joomla-4.x` tag was created first (by me if that is relevant), following the format of the previous `joomla-3.x` tag. There is no `joomla-3` tag.

Currently there are 73 answers with the `joomla-4.x` tag.

Currently there are 51 answers with the `joomla-4` tag.

Do we need both the `joomla-4.x` and `joomla-4` tags?

Comment: Does `joomla-4.x` convey any additional benefit over `joomla-4`?  If both tags are absolutely synonymous, I don't see any benefit to creating a tag-synonym.  If they are identical in meaning, my opinion is that we should retain the more concise tag name only.  I am happy to hear arguments on this topic before any action is taken.  Thanks for bringing this up Neil.

Comment: I agree it is best to standardise on one of these tags. I prefer `joomla-4.x` since it is consistent with the existing `joomla-3.x` tag but am not hugely bothered which one is retained.

Comment: I am comfortable with doing a larger change (versus a smaller change) if it is for good/logical reasons.  Either way, I agree with your observation that it doesn't make sense to have both.

Comment: Well, not a lot of feedback from the community.  Ugh.  I just wanted to mention that there is a third option which I just noticed on [askubuntu.se] where they just use numbers and dots when refering the the Ubuntu version  (`10.10` is the whole tag). Using this convention is the most concise, but will all users prefer this? I don't know.

Comment: https://drupal.stackexchange.com also seems to favour the third option. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com do not seem to use tags for WordPress versions. For consistency, we should probably follow what has gone before and as you point out, we should also consider what is being done on other SE websites.

Comment: I'll ask around in the mods community.